# How to filter some columns values and generate a new column with these values in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
sht.head()
```

[image]

How Can I create a column K containing all non-zero-values from A:J?

Expected result would be: `K = ["A001", "B001", "C001", "D001", "E001", "A002", ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
sht['K']=pd.Series((sht[sht!=0]).values.flatten()).dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I replace the NaNs in sht['K'] by the string "..."?

Comment: `import numpy as np` then`sht['K']=pd.Series((sht[sht!=0]).values.flatten()).replace(np.nan,'...')`

Comment: @pyd any reason not to use `.fillna('...')`?

Comment: Yes we can use `fillna`

Answer (score 1):

Use `agg` in `axis=1`

```
df['K'] = df.agg(lambda s: tuple(s[s!=0]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I've been too vague in the expected result...Your solution provides `(A001, B001, C001, D001, E001, ...)` for `K1` when I expected `A001`.

Comment: @crocefisso so please be specific.... post an expected output for your column k..

Comment: @RafelC sure, I edited the question to show the 6 first row of what `K` should be.